# Memory size used by the app grows VERY fast

Tags: objective-c, macos

Wrote a simple program to fill ALL THE SPACE on my drive. It has a very simple logic:

- 10 Create a file
- 20 Write N (40 in my case) random blocks size of M (100 MiB in my case)
- 30 Close a file
- 40 GOTO 10

Well, I just created a new Cocoa project from scratch and placed the code in the `applicationDidFinishLaunching`. Here is it.

```objective-c
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    fm = [NSFileManager new];

    unsigned long long size = 0;
    unsigned long long sizeMax = 0;

    NSString *path;
    NSData *data;
    NSFileHandle *myHandle;
    for (long i = 0; ; ++i) {
        if (i % 40L == 0) { // N = 40
            sizeMax = [self currentMaxSize];
            size = 0;

            path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/Users/user/Desktop/loltest/lol_%f.txt", [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]];

            [fm createFileAtPath:path contents:[NSData data] attributes:nil];
            [myHandle closeFile];
            myHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:path];
        }

        [myHandle seekToEndOfFile];

        data = [self randomData];
        size += data.length;
        [myHandle writeData:data];
        data = nil;

        if (size >= sizeMax) {
            [myHandle closeFile];
            break;
        }
    }

    NSLog(@"OKAY");
}

- (unsigned long long)currentMaxSize
{
    return [[fm attributesOfFileSystemForPath:@"/" error:nil][NSFileSystemFreeSize] unsignedLongLongValue];
}

- (NSData *)randomData
{
    const int LENGTH = 100 * 1024 * 1024; // M
    char *bytes = (char *)malloc(LENGTH * sizeof(char)); // Well that supposed to be static and dispatched_once, but I removed that when tried to fix leaks

    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < LENGTH; ++i) {
        bytes[i] = arc4random() % 256 - 128; // chosen by fair dice roll.
                                             // guaranteed to be random.
    }

    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:(void *)bytes length:LENGTH];
    free(bytes);
    return data;
}
```

When I ran that one, after 1 minute 1 GiB leaked and still. Ended on the system's memory management window and activity monitor showing me 60 GiB of swap used.

I ran the Instruments which said me that `Overall bytes` section is equal to what the activity monitor shows for the app. However, there is only one object at a time, the allocation graph is a saw, the pointer of the random data is constant between function calls. Maybe `NSData` somehow holds the source array, but I can't solve this puzzle at all.

[image: Saw]

Comment: It's not "Overall Bytes" you need to worry about (because that includes memory that has been released. It's "Live Bytes" that you should worry about (and that looks fine).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably want an @autoreleasepool { } around the content of that loop, otherwise the temporary objects it creates won't be cleaned up. That may be the source of your problem.

Comment: Interesting, never thought that way. It worked, thanks a lot! But I have a question: why if I put the whole function contents in `@autoreleasepool` (or even the contents of `main()` as in UIKit boilerplate) it won't work? Why this is not inherited by nested blocks? And what the point since that to put the `@autorelease` in `main()`? (the docs said `where` to use, not `why`)

Comment: @autoreleasepool releases the objects in its pool at the closing }. The pool *is* inherited, but you're still inside of it.